# How to use parquet files as a source for can in Apache Calcite?

Tags: apache-calcite

I want to read from a parquet file as from a table using Apache Calcite. There are bunch of adapters listed in the [docs](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/adapter.html), but no explicit one for parquet. From the other hand there is adapter for Spark, which can deal with Parquet perfectly. But for some reason I can't really find any example of how to use this spark adapter. Even reading [it's code](https://github.com/apache/calcite/tree/master/spark) I can't say I understand how I need to define Spark's schemas. There is no factory for it... I've tried following code without really understanding how it should work and it obviously doesn't work:

```java
        Class.forName("org.apache.calcite.jdbc.Driver");
        Properties info = new Properties();
        info.setProperty("lex", "JAVA");
        info.setProperty("spark", "true");

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:", info);
        CalciteConnection calciteConnection = connection.unwrap(CalciteConnection.class);
        SchemaPlus rootSchema = calciteConnection.getRootSchema();

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("test")
                .master("local[1]")
                .getOrCreate();
        StopWatch w = StopWatch.createStarted();
        Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().parquet("/tmp/test.parquet");
        ds.select("issue_desc", "valid_from_dttm").show(15);
        ds.printSchema();
        ds.createTempView("sparkTable");
        System.out.println(w.getTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

        FrameworkConfig calciteConfig = Frameworks.newConfigBuilder()
                .parserConfig(SqlParser.Config.DEFAULT)
                .defaultSchema(rootSchema)
                .programs()
                .traitDefs(ConventionTraitDef.INSTANCE, RelDistributionTraitDef.INSTANCE)
                .build();

        RelBuilder builder = RelBuilder.create(calciteConfig);
        RelRunner relRunner = calciteConnection.unwrap(RelRunner.class);

        RelNode test1 = builder
                .scan("sparkTable")
                .build();
        executeNode(relRunner, test1);
```

It simply fails with the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteException: Table 'sparkTable' not found
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInstWithCause.ex(Resources.java:506)
    at org.apache.calcite.runtime.Resources$ExInst.ex(Resources.java:600)
    at org.apache.calcite.tools.RelBuilder.scan(RelBuilder.java:1238)
    at org.apache.calcite.tools.RelBuilder.scan(RelBuilder.java:1265)
    at ru.tinkoff.dwh.hercule.demo.SparkTest.main(SparkTest.java:64)
```

Could please somebody explain how to use it, or share an example, or explain why I can't use spark adapter like this?

Comment: Apache Drill is a distributed MPP query layer for self describing data like Parquet files. @karmal, have you tried this approach ?

Comment: Drill uses Calcite to parse the queries. See [https://www.xenonstack.com/blog/apache-drill-architecture](https://www.xenonstack.com/blog/apache-drill-architecture)